# Load XML node into Java object

Tags: java, xml, optimization

I have a large (1MB+) XML file, and I'm trying to create an object where the variables of the object equal what's in the XML node.  Currently, I just use .evaluate() for each variable, but that takes far too long (~1 sec per object, and when I'm trying to load 56 objects, I can't wait a minute just to start up).  Some parts are empty, otherwise I'd just load the node into a string and parse from there.  I'm pretty new to this, what I do know how to search doesn't result in anything useful.  I'm currently using the DOM parser.  What is an efficient way to load all these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the XML follows some sort of established schema, I would recommend using JAXB. When you unmarshal the XML, you will end up with an object structure matching that of the XML.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for helping a newbie out!